# Is it always required to create the target DB table in Informatica before starting the workflow?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I want to create a target table in Oracle using Informatica. But I see a fatal execution error saying table does not exist.
I don't wanna have to create a table each time I execute a task in Informatica.

Please help!

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/za3HR.png)

Comment: I am not clear about the question, why would you need to create a table everytime?

Comment: I want to push the results of the task into a new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create new table only once before running the workflow(if the table is not already created).